# running Greasemonkey-created code in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm completely new to userscripts. I have a small one written to add a link that calls a javascript function:

```
...
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3
// ==UserScript==  

    //define functions
    $k = jQuery.noConflict();
    function testFn() {
        alert("Successful test!");
    }

    //add a test link to the DOM
    var testLink = "<a href=\"javascript:testFn()\">TEST LINK</a></div>";
    $k("body").prepend(testLink);

    //add custom functions to the DOM
    var scr = document.createElement("script");
    scr.type = "text/javascript";
    scr.textContent = "$k = jQuery.noConflict();\n" + testFn;    
    $k("body").prepend(scr);

    //add jQuery to the DOM
    var jQueryAdd = document.createElement("script");    
    jQueryAdd.type = "text/javascript";
    jQueryAdd.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"; 
    $k("body").prepend(jQueryAdd);
```

The script populates my DOM as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $k = jQuery.noConflict();

    function testFn() {
        alert("Testing");
    }
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="javascript:testFn()">TEST LINK</a>
```

But, whenever I click on the test link, the function does not execute, and the console throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: testFn is not defined
```

I did a fair amount of Googling and, from what I read, this is supposed to be possible. Plus, when I simple save the edited page as its own HTML file, the link works fine. Am I missing something extremely obvious?

*Side note: I've also tried putting the jQuery source on the same domain. No dice.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the HTML element and not the jQuery object

```
$k("body").prepend(jQueryAdd[0]);
```

---

A better approach, since you are already using jQuery, would be to attach an event listener to your link.

Here a better implementation of your code:

```
// create a closure and define jQuery as $ inside it
(function($) {

  // create the anchor element, add the `href` attr and a text
  var $testLink = $('<a>', {href: '#0', text: 'click me'});
  // attach an event listener to the generated anchor
  $testLink.on('click', function() {
    alert('hey');
  });
  // append the generated anchor to the body
  $testLink.appendTo('body');

})(jQuery) // calling `(jQuery)` will automatically run this closure
```

Comment: If you look at the DOM, it is actually defined there  -- added by grease monkey in the third code block. So that's not enough?

Comment: updated my answer explaining why your code wasn't working. By the way I suggest you to use an approach similar to the one I've posted right after the explanation. It's much easier and maintainable (and faster)

Comment: jQueryAdd *is* an HTML element:

`var jQueryAdd = document.createElement("script");`

Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: jquery wraps its elements in arrays managed by jquery itself, calling it with `[0]` will select just the real html element